# Zxing iOS: Crop a BinaryBitMap

Tags: c++, iphone, zxing

I am trying read 3 barcodes at the same time, so I need to crop image in 3 parts. I tried this but it fails:

```
Ref<Result> MultiFormatReader::decodeInternal(Ref<BinaryBitmap> image){
   try{
      DecodeHints hints = DecodeHints::DEFAULT_HINT;
      oned::MultiFormatOneDReader od(hints);
      image->crop(0,0,100,image->getHeight()); //This method is not implemented, I don't know why.
      return od.decode(image, hints);
   } catch (ReaderException const& re){
      (void)re;
   }
   throw ReaderException("No code detected");
```

Does someone have an idea?

Thank you!

Comment: How does it fail? More info?

Comment: It fails because crop is not implemented in ZXing, I thought it was, but when I looked for it that's what I found: "throw IllegalArgumentException("...");"